# For any set $A$, there is some $x$ not in $A$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am working through a set theory text and am having trouble giving a formal proof of the above statement. So far I have:

Suppose the contrary. Then there exists a set $A$ such that $x\in A$ for all $x$. Thus $A$ is the set of all sets, which gives rise to Russell's paradox.

Is there a more concise or direct proof of this fact using the axioms of $\sf ZFC$? I am concerned about asserting that $A$ is the "set of all sets."

Comment: $A$ does not contain itself, by the axiom of foundation (or rather, by its consequence that our the universe is well founded).

Comment: We do not need to use the axiom of foundation. By Cantor's theorem, there is no surjection from $A$ to its power set, so there must be some subset of $A$ which does not belong to $A$.

Answer (score 2):

A more direct (but very similar) proof can be concieved: even though Russell's paradox is often thought as a limitative result, the argument it uses is precisely a proof of your result:

Let $x$ be the subset $\{a \in A  \ | \ a \notin a\}$ of $A$. $x \in A$ is absurd, hence $x \notin A$.

Note that assuming fondation, $x$ is equal to $A$.

Comment: One of my favorites. I call this "Global anti-choice"

Answer (score 1):

We can prove that for any set $A$, there exist some $x$ such that $x$ is not in $A$.
For any set $A$ we take $x = A$ by the axiom of foundation $A$ is not in $A$.
Hence for any set $A$, there is some $x$ not in $A$ By counterexample.

Comment: Russel's paradox is not that a set contains itself. No matter how unintuitive a set that contains itself may sound, there is no logical problem with the concept. The paradox is that "the set of all sets that do not contain themselves" both contains itself and doesn't, simultaneously, or rather, neither contains itself nor doesn't contain itself.

Comment: "by the axiom of foundation" now the proof is correct?

Comment: Yes, that's better.